# When are next moderator elections?

Tags: support, election

When are next moderator elections?

How many moderator positions will be available?

When does the current moderators' term of office conclude?

Answer (score 4):

> When are next moderator elections?
>
> How many moderator positions will be available?

We don't know, elections are on a as-needed basis.

> When does the current moderators' term of office conclude?

There isn't one. We can step down or be removed by SE, but otherwise it's a life term.

Answer (score 2):

As explained [on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/984/should-community-moderators-be-elected-for-life-or-have-terms), moderators are not limited to terms. The next moderator election will be whenever the community and the SE team decide that the moderation workload on the site exceeds what the current moderators can do, and the number of positions available will be determined by the need. It's usually 1 or 2.

Comment: Is there any form of recall procedure, or other formal process for the community to voice their discontent with the moderators? Preferably, it should be possible to bring such concerns forth without the complainant facing a risk of immediate and unexplained suspension of access.

Comment: @HalfdanFaber [There is a procedure to recall a moderator](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151633/151385). And just to make it very clear, asking for the resignation of a current mod or voicing concerns in no way puts you in danger of being suspended. Suspensions are audited by all other mods and the SE community team, any misuse by mods of the suspension feature would be quickly overturned by SE.

Comment: @MadScientist: Thanks, appreciate the information.