# How does a moderator lose his diamond?

Tags: discussion, election

Moderators are appointed for life as discussed in [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4923/when-are-next-moderator-elections) post.  Not having a term limit seems reasonable, but is there no way for a moderator to be recalled by the community?  No reelection and no recall authority seems rather like a dictatorship.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you think a moderator is out of line use the ["contact us" link](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) at the bottom of the page to explain your position to the team. Moderators have been removed in the past.

[Other moderators can ask to have a colleague removed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151633/2509) This is the officially sanctioned process for "normal" removal of a moderator.

Beta site get *pro tem* moderators appointed by the team rather than elected and they have to run for election to retain their position after the site launches. And permanent moderators have been known to resign.

At this time that is it.